# Android not syncing anymore

Tags: wi-fi, sync

My wifi doesn't turn green anymore, just stays grey/white, therefore my google apps do not sync anymore. I have internet. HTC Desire 2.3.7

Any help?

Comment: Did you verify that they're not actually syncing?  Did you reboot?  Did you try a manual sync?  Etc.

Comment: yes, I tried a manual sync, I also rebooted

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem too, but I have found that it is correlated to low internal memory on the phone. Try clearing the cache from some apps and uninstalling the ones you don't use, it helped for me. Nexus One 2.3.7

Comment: Very true. I have an HTC Desire myself, and this is indeed the reason. When the notification about low space goes away (at around 15 MB free), then syncing resumes.

Comment: On my HTC Incredible, low space can be caused by any app, even if there is sufficient total space. However, it doesn't tell me what app and I have to guess, usually by clearing the cache/data of the app I'm using when it pops up with low memory.

Comment: @KevinM yeah, I even installed this https://market.android.com/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.acc.pro to help with cleaning up

Comment: Mine has 6GB free internal memory (Droid2), still have been hitting the issue now. logcat reports an HTTP request timeout on Google's server (umm, do they only have one? or why does it stick to that IP?). So there must be other reasons why this occurs. Waiting the 3rd day already for a "server-side fixup".